# How to control XAML controls from another View?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, methods, win-universal-app

I'm building a Universal Windows Platform app where I have a few controls on the `MarvelMenu.xaml` page and I need to be able to control them from the `MainPage.xaml`, especially the `MyProgressRing` control. For that I created a helper method called `Search` in the `MarvelMenu.xaml` page as follows:

```
public partial class MarvelMenu : Page
{

    public async void Search(ObservableCollection<Character> MarvelCharacters, string searchedCharacter)
    {
        MyProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MyProgressRing.IsActive = true;
        DataModel.ErrorMessage = "";
        DataModel.MarvelCharacters.Clear();
        Task t = MarvelFacade.PopulateMarvelCharactersByNameAsync(searchedCharacter, MarvelCharacters);
        await t;
        MyProgressRing.IsActive = false;
        MyProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

My problem is that those commands don't work. Other methods on this same page do the same command and it works fine, but because this method is called from the "MainPage.xaml", as follows, it doesn't work.

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private MarvelMenu _MarvelMenu = new MarvelMenu();
    private DataModel _DataModel = new DataModel();

    public void AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
    {
        _MarvelMenu.Search(_DataModel.MarvelCharacters, sender.Text);
        _MarvelMenu.MyProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Although the Task t in the Search method is executed just fine... Point being, the XAML code is not working... And below is a part of it, the `MyProgressRing` that isn't working.

```
<Page x:Class="Marvel_sDatabase.Views.MarvelMenu"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:Marvel_sDatabase.Views"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:data="using:Marvel_sDatabase.Models"
      Loaded="Page_Loaded"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ProgressRing Name="MyProgressRing"
                  x:FieldModifier="public"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.RowSpan="3"
                  Width="50"
                  Height="50"
                  Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

I would really appreciate any help, as I'm a hobby and newbie to developing apps.

Comment: Create Dependency Properties in your control.

Comment: As I said, I'm not very familiar with coding just yet, could you please show me how I could implement Dependency Properties in my project?

Comment: Jamie Eltringham, what did you do that for?